# Method to create two bevels without boolean and bad topology

Tags: modeling, mesh, topology, bevel

How can I create this bevel with good topology in Blender without compromising on the shading quality? I attempted to make the bevel by creating one of the two bevels and then cutting the other bevel using a boolean object, but the resulting topology and shading turned out to be very bad. Are there any alternative methods or techniques that I could use to achieve the desired bevel while maintaining good topology and shading quality? Any help or guidance on this matter would very helpful[image].

Answer (score 1):

Maybe do it this way:

Do a bevel on the sides (here it's a 5 segments bevel only, you probably want more), don't forget to merge by distance the overlapping vertices at the bottom:

[image]

Give your object a *Boolean* modifier with a cylinder (here a 16 vertex cylinder) as *Object*:

[image]

Apply the Boolean, remove the faces and also dissolve all the remaining vertices:

[image]

Fill the faces:

[image]